# Reactive Property is not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unirx

I try to study UniRX. And I write the simple script for controlling player:

'''

```
using UnityEngine;
using UniRx;
using UniRx.Triggers;

namespace playerV1
{
    public class Inputs : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static Inputs Instance { get; private set; }
        public ReadOnlyReactiveProperty<Vector2> ImpulseForce { get; private set; }
        private void Awake()
        {
            Instance = this;
            ImpulseForce = this.FixedUpdateAsObservable()
                .Select
                (
                _ =>
                {
                    float x = Input.GetAxis("HorizontalX");
                    float z = Input.GetAxis("HorizontalZ");
                    return new Vector2(x, z).normalized;
                }
                )
                .ToReadOnlyReactiveProperty();
        }
    }
    
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float coefficient;
        private Rigidbody _rg;

        private void Awake()
        {
            _rg = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
        private void Start()
        {
            Inputs inputs = Inputs.Instance;
            //Debug.Log(inputs.ImpulseForce); I get the mistake here
            inputs.ImpulseForce
                .Where(force => force != Vector2.zero)
                .Subscribe
                (
                force =>
                {
                    _rg.AddForce(coefficient * new Vector3(force.x, 0, force.y), ForceMode.Impulse);
                }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

'''

But I get mistake:
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
playerV1.PlayerController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:43)"
I don't understand what is wrong here.
What is problem might be here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I had found the mistake. It was not in code. I put both monobehaviours in one file. When I created two files with the same monobehaviours names it started to work fine.
Bless Unity spaghetti!